# Remove Button's Text Outline

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to remove the rectangle in the button's text when clicked?

[image]

Comment: Did you come to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your own button to turn off the ShowFocusCues property:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
  protected override bool ShowFocusCues {
    get {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Replace the button you are using with this one.

Comment: This is a really slick answer (as paqogomez stated), +1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the dotted line around Cancel?

This is windows way of showing focus. If you want to get rid of it, change the focus to some other element.

Something like this:

```
private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus = false;
}
```

In WPF you can change the `FocusVisualElement` (setting it to 0), but Winforms doesnt have a property like that.

Comment: `'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Focused' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FlatAppearance` property like this:

```
this.buttonNameHere.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the button, go look for "FlatAppearance". Once you have found it you should set the values of the MouseDownBackColor & MouseOverBackColor to Transparent, this sets the colors of the background of the button to transparent when you clock or hover on it. Then you make the FlatStyle to "Flat".